# ClosedXML negative duration

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

I am creating report avaible to downlad as excel file. In the report I have durations as string `HH:MM`. Everything looks fine untill durations comes as `"-HH:MM"` For non negative durations excel works great but for negative it shows like `########`

Here is what I am doing in C#:

```
worksheet.Cell("F" + _freeFrom).Value = totalDuration;
worksheet.Cell("F" + _freeFrom).Style.NumberFormat.Format = "H:mm";
```

Anyone have idea how to solve that problem ?

Answer (score 1):

That is a "problem" in Excel itself which does not show negative time values in the default date system. You can switch to the 1904 date system with ClosedXML like this:

```
workbook.SetUse1904DateSystem(true);
```

For more information about the Excel date systems see [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/214330).